# Ignore warnings whose messages contain a specific string

Tags: python, python-3.x, suppress-warnings

I don't want warnings whose message contains "property" to be printed. I know that I can ignore a warning by specifying  its whole message with:

```
import warnings

warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", message="All message displayed in console.")
```

I need something like:

```
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", message="*property*")
```

I also know that I can disable warnings for a specific part of the code with:

```
import warnings

with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
    function_that_causes_warnings()
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The *message* parameter of [`filterwarnings`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#warnings.filterwarnings) is a regular expression, therefore you should be able to use

```
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", message=".*property.*")
```

Where `.*` matches zero or more occurrences of any character.